# How to add a Drawable object to a Parcel object in android?

Tags: android, parcel

I'm facing problem in adding a drawable object to a Parcel object, in order to send an object from one activity to another activity.

There are methods like writeString(String) to add strings to a Parcel object. But do not know how to add a Drawable to the Parcel object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add a `Drawable` to a `Parcel`, as `Drawable` does not implement the `Parcelable` interface. Certain types of `Drawable` might implement `Parcelable`, but I am not aware of any.

You can put in the `Parcel` some identifier (e.g., drawable resource ID) and have the recipient obtain the `Drawable` on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try wrapping the Drawable inside an object that implements Parcelable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) and [BitmapDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html).

Let's say you have a **Drawable** called *drawable* and a **Parcel** (in which the object should be written) called *parcel*.

To write a [Drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html) into a [Parceable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html):

```
if ( drawable != null ) {
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    parcel.writeParcelable(bitmap, flags);
}
else {
    parcel.writeParcelable(null, flags);
}
```

To read the Drawable from the Parceable:

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) in.readParcelable(getClass().getClassLoader());
if ( bitmap != null ) {
    drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
}
else {
    drawable = null;
}
```

In particular, since the constructor [BitmapDrawable (Bitmap bitmap)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#BitmapDrawable%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29) has been deprecated, you might want to use [BitmapDrawable (Resources res, Bitmap bitmap)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#BitmapDrawable%28android.content.res.Resources,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29) instead.

```
drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
```